# Vacuum tube voltage regulator - capacitor on the output

Tags: voltage-regulator, vacuum-tube

I'm thinking about building a tube-based voltage regulator to provide the power for the screen grids of the output tubes.

I have seen multiple designs of this and am currently thinking of doing it this way:
[image: Circuit diagram]

If I place a capacitor (say, 100uF) on the output to help with the peaks, will something bad happen?

Comment: It might do depending on what type it is.